# Querying xml into structure

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I believe I am getting `XDocument` and `XElement` aspects confused. I am trying to:

1. Load an xml file
2. Query an attribute of an element's name
3. Write aspects of the found element to a structure.

Simple Structure, called `Rule`:

```
public struct Rule
{
    public String keyDB;
    public String eventLog;
}
```

XML Structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Error_List>
  <Error code="0xC004C003">
      <KeyDB>
        default key
      </KeyDB>
      <EventLog>
        default event
      </EventLog>
  </Error>
  <Error code="000000000">
      <KeyDB>
        non-default key
      </KeyDB>
      <EventLog>
        non-default event
      </EventLog>
  </Error>
</Error_List>
```

Set `Rule rule = new Rule()`;
If I pass into my method `"000000000"` I am looking to set `rule.keyDB = "non-default key"` and `rule.eventLog = "non-default event"`. I'm pretty sure that this is possible, but that I just have my variables mixed up.

**Edit:**
My code, thus far, has been unsuccessful and incomplete. I have

```
IEnumerable<XElement> query =   (from elem in rulesXml.Root.Elements("Error")
                                where (String)elem.Attribute("code") == this.errorCode.ToString()
                                select elem);
```

but am unsure where to go from there.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq-to-XML is extremely powerful and quite straightforward to understand once you master Linq. You can find a lot of tutorials about these two topics.

Here is what you can do:

```
string myCode = "000000000";  // Error Code to find
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load("C:/Path to the file.xml");  // Loads the Xml file to a XDocument

Rule rule = (from errorNode in xDocument.Descendants("Error")    // Go through Error elements
             where errorNode.Attribute("code").Value == myCode   // That has the specified code attribute
             select new Rule
             {
                 keyDB = errorNode.Element("KeyDB").Value,       // Gets the KeyDB element value of the Error node
                 eventLog = errorNode.Element("EventLog").Value  // Gets the EventLog element value of the Error node
             }).FirstOrDefault();
```

### Update

If an `Error` element can have no code attribute or no `KeyDB` or `EventLog` attribute. Use the explicit type casting to retrieve their value. ie. Instead of writing `Element.Attribute("...").Value` write `(string)Element.Attribute("...")` (same for `Element("...")`)

```
Rule rule = (from errorNode in xDocument.Descendants("Error")      // Go through Error elements
             where (string)errorNode.Attribute("code") == myCode   // That has the specified code attribute
             select new Rule
             {
                 keyDB = (string)errorNode.Element("KeyDB"),       // Gets the KeyDB element value of the Error node
                 eventLog = (string)errorNode.Element("EventLog")  // Gets the EventLog element value of the Error node
             }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm sure this is exactly right, and I still have an error in my code. It's returning `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on the `select new Rule...` step. Do you know what would cause that?

Comment: @Adam_G Maybe an Error element doesn't have a KeyDB element or EventLog element. I've updated my post to support this.

Comment: Yup, just a stupid typo in my code. But all typos are "stupid" typos. :-) Fixed!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Since an `Error` will always be defined by its code, I decided to make this is an attribute rather than just a child node. Therefore, it will always have one.

Comment: If I wanted to use a static class called `Rule`, with the same variables, instead of a structure, what would I need to change in the code above?

Comment: Probably should've said `abstract` class.

Comment: @Adam_G What would be the derived class of `Rule`?

Comment: I just did some more reading. It wouldn't be abstract, it would be static. I'd like the same type of structure, but accessible by all of my classes.

Answer (score 0):

## Try using the ILookup:

`Error code` is set as the key for the `lookup`.

```
public struct Rule
{
    public String keyDB;
    public String eventLog;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("src.xml");

        ILookup<string, Rule> lookup = xdoc.Descendants("Error").ToLookup(x => x.Attribute("code").Value, x => new Rule() { keyDB = x.Element("KeyDB").Value, eventLog = x.Element("EventLog").Value });

        //Perform operation based on the error code from the lookup

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```